# Formatting number when user enter digit in EditText

Tags: android

I have to format number as user enters number in `Edit Text`. If an user inputs single digit then it should appear `0,0x`. If the user enters two digit then it should appear `0,xx`. If three digits then `x,xx`. If four digits then `xx,xx`. If five digits then `xxx,xx`. If six digits then `x.xxx,xx`. If seven digit then `xx.xxx,xx`. If eight digit then `xxx.xxx,xx`.Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want all zero after accepting particular string ?

Comment: why there is no `0` where entering three digit?

Comment: in x,xx there can be 0.

Comment: is 8 you maximum digit limit you are receiving in input ?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android

Comment: @VaibhavAlone hey have to tried my suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `addTextChangedListener`

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             // Write your logic here to parse the text
             // and format it in the way you want to.
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if(afterFormat){
                afterFormat = false;
                return;
            }
            afterFormat = true;
            // TODO format digits
            ......
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but this method goes into loop and keyboard hangs

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by setting an input filer to the text field.

```
private InputFilter myFilter = new  InputFilter(){

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
       //your code to modify the input text. 
       return modified_input;
    }
};
editText.setFilters(new inputFilterp[]{})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method by which you can achieve that i.e.

1. Monitor text change by `addTextChangedListener` or something like that..
2. When you get string, iterate it with respect to `0` till it reaches eight 
   digit.

   ```
   while (string.length() < 8) {
       string = "0" + string;
   }
   ```
3. Pattern string in desire format with `String.format()`.

   ```
   String.format("%s.%s,%s", string);   // pattern you want
   ```

So here is the full code :

```
 edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            text.setText("");
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String string = s.toString();
            if (string.length() < 8) {
                while (string.length() < 8) {
                    string = "0" + string;
                }
            }               
            text.setText(String.format("%s.%s,%s", string.substring(0, 3), string
                    .substring(3, 6), string.substring(6, 8)));
        }
});
```